PhpStorm 2024.2.4 - Debug/Run open internal browser at specific url
I have:

A project in my local XAMPP webserver
I code in PhpStorm and if I start the debug/run command, I just want to open the internal browser on a specific URL without relative path to the current file. Like:

http://localhost/projectpath/
instead of
http://localhost/projectpath/current/openedfile.php
What I'm missing?
I already tried certain options in the deployment settings, but the JavaScript Debug option don't give me the internal browser option as browser.

PHP Web Page is the type that allows specifying custom URL for PHP debug. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configuration-php-web-application.html External browser will be used (it's always better to use a proper browser). P.S. JavaScript Debug type will offer Chrome based browsers only anyway.

Any "Open in XXX browser" actions will use your default Deployment entry to build the URL (or will use the built-in simple web server if you do not have any). In any case -- that will use real file URL (i.e. /path/to/file.php) and not a nice URL like /my-endpoint). I'm not sure if a built-in preview can serve the custom/nice URL.

Sounds sad. If i have all i need in one area. But alt+tab just let my working-flow stumble everytime :/ Especially as i have already 5 programs open at all.
